# Apigee to Send Host Header to Endpoint

Tags: apigee

This is a question relating to Apigee configuration.

I want to be able to send the request "Host" header back to our endpoint.

For example :

```
Request : int.api.com/path/UUID?apiKey=key
```

or

```
Request : test.api.com/path/UUID?apiKey=key
```

I should see in the request `X-Host=int.api.com`.

I have created a policy that sends back a header X-Host but currently its fixed.

I don't know how to get it to dynamically set he Host header based on the request Host header.

I have tried many things.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try using an AssignMsg to save the request host header (request.header.x-host) as a another variable (let's call it `user3645204.variable`).  Then you can access `user3645204.variable` in your response flow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a policy setup to send back this info as a either the response body or as key/values in the response header

```
<ReleaseInfo>
    <RequestTimestamp>%system.time#</RequestTimestamp>
    <Host>%system.interface.eth0#</Host>
    <VirtualHost>%virtualhost.name#</VirtualHost>
    <ApigeeEnvironmentName>%apiproxy.name# - %proxy.name#</ApigeeEnvironmentName>
    <ApigeeApplication>%environment.name#</ApigeeApplication>
    <DeployedApplicationName>ProxyAPIName</DeployedApplicationName>
    <ServiceVersion>1.2.1</ServiceVersion>
</ReleaseInfo>
```

The system.interface.eth0 and virtualhost.name fit my requirements better